# quarkus project not generating classes with hibernate-jpamodelgen

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, metamodel, jpamodelgen

I'm having troubles generating metamodel classes with hibernate-jpamodelgen to use with Criterta.

To reproduce, generate a quarkus project on quarkus.io with Hibernate ORM and add the following dependency to the pom:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

In this demo project, there is a class MyEntity:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    public String field;
}
```

I expect hibernate-jpamodelgen to generate a class MyEntity_, as it does with all my @Entities in other Spring Boot projects.

On Spring Boot, I have to add `jaxb-api` and `jaxb-runtime` as well. But then its working flawlessly. On quarkus I've added those and tried quarkus-jaxb. It's still not working.

I've enabled annotation processors in IntelliJ and set the Maven output to DEBUG. There were no Errors.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on Quarkus 2.x, please observe it still uses Hibernate 5.6 under the hood, so the metamodel generator will work when you align the version. Try using `org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:5.6.15.Final`.

Comment: 5.6.15.Final worked :) Thank you! I've tried an older version before which didn't work...